# Xamarin.Forms Firebase User Authentication 401 unauthorized error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, http-status-code-401

I am trying to use Firebase in Xamarin.Forms. I am using [this library by Ricardo](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin). Till now I am able to get, put, post data without Authentication. Also able to get event realtime as data change. But I am stuck with Post data with authentication.

This is my code:

```
            var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://XXXXXX-bdded.firebaseio.com/test");
            var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig("AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXE"));
            var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("pal@gmail.com", "abc@1234");
            var item =await firebase
              .Child("MyMeetings")
              .WithAuth(auth.FirebaseToken) 
              .PostAsync("Please Post me");
```

Database rules are:

```
{
 "rules": {
         "test":{
           "$uid": {
         ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
         ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
          }
      }
   }
 }
```

It's throwing **401 unauthorized error**. What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to see in the issues of that git library it is mentioned [there](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/issues/25).

Just pass false as second parameter to PostAsync() like this - `var item = await FirebaseClient
                  .Child("someTable")
                  .WithAuth(Auth.FirebaseToken)
                  .PostAsync(someObject, false);`